# Newbie looking for assistance

Tags: pine-script

Most of what I see are formula's on a chart but I would like to overlay different securities on the same chart without formula's.

I want to add a empty chart and save it for later viewing.
So I suppose I would like to create a chart that shows the S&P,BTC,VIX,GDX lines on the same chart.

I hope that made sense, not sure of the right jargon, maybe a list of words that would point me in the right diection for those who would rather not make it too easy for me.

Answer (score 1):

You can't get an empty chart, because there must be one main symbol, which would set a bunch of parameters, like timezone, session, mintick and many other. 
The next thing is depends on what kind of data you need: candles for every security or `close` will be enough. If the latter, then you can require data via `security` function, and then plot it via `plot`:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
plot(security("SPX", timeframe.period, close))
plot(security("GDX", timeframe.period, close))
```

40 security calls allowed per a script.

If you'd like to see the data as candles, then you should require OHLC data via `security` and plot it via `plotcandle`:

```
//@version=4
study("My Script")
spxOpen = security("SPX", timeframe.period, open)
spxHigh = security("SPX", timeframe.period, high)
spxLow = security("SPX", timeframe.period, low)
spxClose = security("SPX", timeframe.period, close)
plotcandle(spxOpen, spxHigh, spxLow, spxClose, color=spxOpen > spxClose ? color.red : color.green)

gdxOpen = security("GDX", timeframe.period, open)
gdxHigh = security("GDX", timeframe.period, high)
gdxLow = security("GDX", timeframe.period, low)
gdxClose = security("GDX", timeframe.period, close)
plotcandle(gdxOpen, gdxHigh, gdxLow, gdxClose, color=spxOpen > spxClose ? color.red : color.green)
```